# Laradock ошибка при запуске

Tags: laravel, bash, docker, laradock

Здраствуйте. Сломался запуск **laradock** ( до этого работало нормально ,изменения в конфигурацию не вносились). Команда `export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(dig +short host.docker.internal)`
выдает `up.sh: 1: export: out;: bad variable name`
.Команда `docker system prune` не помогла. В какую сторону смотреть? Спасибо

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что домена `host.docker.internal` не существует.

Comment: А как его вернуть на место?) И по какой причине он мог исчезнуть? Ничего не коректрировалось и не менялось

Comment: а где и как вы выполняете эту команту?

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае проблема в немного другой плоскости лежала:

```
file /etc/resolv.conf
```

значение поля `nameserver 172.24.0.1` (может быть другое)
нужно поменять на `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Т.е. ты хочешь сказать, что поменяв днс на гугловские, у тебя начал резолвиться хост `host.docker.internal`? О_о

Comment: На момент написания даного поста да. Хотя решение временное ,проблема была с глобальным апдейтом докера